# ListView in ViewPager fragment not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

This is the layout file for the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/db1_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/channelMessageList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<View 
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/enter_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:background="@drawable/send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:text="@string/send_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code with the unwanted bits removed

```
public class ChannelMessageListFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
MessageMap _mInstance;
Button sendButton;
EditText messageView;
BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver;
List<String> messages;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_channel_message_list, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.channelMessageList);
    _mInstance = MessageMap.getInstance(getActivity());
    String channelName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

    if(bundle != null) {
        channelName = bundle.getString("channel_name");
    }

    getActivity().setTitle(channelName);
    messages = _mInstance.getMessages(channelName);

    if(messages == null) {
        messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I debugged the application and the message list is not empty, in fact it has the exact stuff I need to be displayed! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: our linearlayout which hass the listview in it has a weight but your parent layout doesnt have a weightsum, try always to set different background colors of your views and have a look if the appear.

Comment: just remember that you provide an empty dataset to the adapter, the listview will not be filled.

Comment: As already mentioned I ran debug mode and confirmed dataset is not empty

Comment: Can you put a log before this line and see if the message is null or not :

if(messages == null) {
        messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

I know you said that the message is not null but I just want to make  sure if its really not. And also can you change your : listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.channelMessageList); to listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.channelMessageList);

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/channelMessageList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**To**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/channelMessageList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**First :** Can you put a log before this line and see if the message is null or not :

Like here:

```
Log.i("Some Result", messages.toString());
if(messages == null) { 
messages = new ArrayList<String>(); 
}
```

I know you said that the message is not null but I just want to make sure if its really not.

And also,
Try changing :

```
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.channelMessageList);
```

To

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.channelMessageList);
```

Comment: I shall try this out, just as an update: I made a static string array and it shows up! About the list being emtpy, I will add the log and paste the contents as soon as i get hands on my machine.